# I have 5 choices in a test. I have a csv database. When I press on one of the buttons, I want the Text on the button to change to the next header

Tags: java, android, loops, layout

I have 5 choices in a test. I have a csv database which I read the headers and answers from. When I press on one of the buttons, I want the Text on the button to change to the next header. I want to use a "for" loop for that. How will I keep the same layout, but change the text on the buttons in this for loop?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

int say,may=0;

Button a,b,c,d,e;
private List<WeatherSample> weatherSamples=new ArrayList<>();
String[][] deneme=new String[20][7];

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Button asikki = (Button) findViewById(R.id.asikki);
    final Button bsikki = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bsikki);
    final Button csikki = (Button) findViewById(R.id.csikki);
    final Button dsikki = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dsikki);
    final Button esikki = (Button) findViewById(R.id.esikki);

    String line = "";
    a = (Button) findViewById(R.id.asikki);
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bsikki);
    c = (Button) findViewById(R.id.csikki);
    d = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dsikki);
    e = (Button) findViewById(R.id.esikki);

    InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.data);

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8"))
    );

    try {
        // step over header line
        reader.readLine();

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

            may++;
            String sira = Integer.toString(may);
            String[] tokens = line.split(",");
            WeatherSample sample = new WeatherSample();

            deneme[may][0] = tokens[0];
            deneme[may][1] = tokens[1];
            deneme[may][2] = tokens[2];
            deneme[may][3] = tokens[3];
            deneme[may][4] = tokens[4];
            deneme[may][5] = tokens[5];
            deneme[may][6] = tokens[6];
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    for (int say=0;say<10;say++){
        a.setText("A) " + deneme[1][0]);
        b.setText("B) " + deneme[1][1]);
        c.setText("C) " + deneme[1][2]);
        d.setText("D) " + deneme[1][3]);
        e.setText("E) " + deneme[1][4]);

        asikki.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                asikki.setText("bilgin");
                asikki.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                asikki.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            }
        });

        bsikki.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                bsikki.setText("bilgin");
                bsikki.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                bsikki.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            }
        });

        csikki.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                csikki.setText("bilgin");
                csikki.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                csikki.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            }
        });

        dsikki.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dsikki.setText("bilgin");
                dsikki.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                dsikki.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            }
        });

        esikki.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                esikki.setText("bilgin");
                esikki.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                esikki.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            }
        });

     }

}
```

Comment: If this is an Android question, please use the Android tag.  The answer for Android is definitely not the same as it would be for, say, Java Swing on a laptop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for` loop is something to be executed immediately, it doesn't wait, you only need the listener

```
    asikki.setText(deneme[0][0]);
    asikki.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    asikki.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

    asikki.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        int say = 1;
        public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO check say isn't out of bound
            asikki.setText("A) " +deneme[say++][0]);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Happy, Now I have the following lines in my code:

```
int say = 1;
asikki.setText(deneme[0][0]);
asikki.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
asikki.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

asikki.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        say++;
        asikki.setText("A) " +deneme[say][1]);
        bsikki.setText("B) " +deneme[say][2]);
        csikki.setText("C) " +deneme[say][3]);
        dsikki.setText("D) " +deneme[say][4]);
        esikki.setText("E) " +deneme[say][5]);
    }
});
```